# Avoid temporal coupling in class that requires establishing a connection

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I am designing a class that provides a means for interacting with a Bluetooth Device.
My design roughly looks like this:

```
class Device
{
    private bool _isConnected;
    private readonly ulong _bluetoothAddress;

    public event EventHandler<Message> MessageReceived;

    public Device(ulong bluetoothAddress)
    {
        _bluetoothAddress = bluetoothAddress;
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        // Async connection logic...

        _isConnected = true;
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(Message message)
    {
        if (!_isConnected)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not connected");
        }

        // Send logic...
    }
}
```

In order to send a message to the device, the client must call `ConnectAsync` to put the device in a connected state. Then, messages can be sent via `SendMessage` and received via the event `Message received`.

What I don't like about this design, is that it introduces temporal coupling into the API. The client is always required to call `ConnectAsync` before `SendMessage`. Lazily calling `ConnectAsync`
from `SendMessage` when the device is disconnected is also not an option, since the connection must be established to receive events.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to my other, more straightforward answer, I'd propose some kind of device "factory" that will handle this for you:

```cs
public class DeviceFactory
{
    public async Task<Device> GetBluetoothDevice(string address)
    {
        var device = new Device(address);

        await device.ConnectAsync();

        return device;
    }
}
```

You could use this to abstract away any amount of complex initialization logic.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
if (!_isConnected)
{
    await ConnectAsync();
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I also need to receive messages from the device, which also requires the connection to be established.